# How to fix PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class 'Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport' not found

Tags: yii2

When I try to send an emails from hosting (i've " PHP Fatal Error – [yii\base\ErrorException]

### Class 'Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport' not found )

I havn't any problems on local server.
As anybody knows how to corrige this?
Thank you.

```
1. in /home/u536070/operettalife.ru/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/SmtpTransport.php at line 23
14151617181920212223242526272829303132

                     * @author Chris Corbyn
 *
 * @method Swift_SmtpTransport setUsername(string $username) Set the username to authenticate with.
 * @method string              getUsername()                 Get the username to authenticate with.
 * @method Swift_SmtpTransport setPassword(string $password) Set the password to authenticate with.
 * @method string              getPassword()                 Get the password to authenticate with.
 * @method Swift_SmtpTransport setAuthMode(string $mode)     Set the auth mode to use to authenticate.
 * @method string              getAuthMode()                 Get the auth mode to use to authenticate.
 */
class Swift_SmtpTransport extends Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport
{
    /**
     * Create a new SmtpTransport, optionally with $host, $port and $security.
     *
     * @param string $host
     * @param int    $port
     * @param string $security
     */
    public function __construct($host = 'localhost', $port = 25, $security = null)


2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
```

Comment: Did you check that the class is there? Where is your import? If it is working on your local machine but it doesn't work in the production server, you are probably importing it correctly but, on the production machine, it cannot find the class, maybe the folder permissions are wrong, or more likely, the file containing the class is not there. How did you install it? Did you copy the contents of your development machine or did you install using composer?

Comment: @RaulSauco Thank you very much for your answer. You're right it was a file transfer problem. After having completely removed from productive server project and transferred the whole project again everything is working well now. I was cocentred on the error and did not see the problem wide enough.

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved, maybe you can write an answer with more details on how you solve the problem and accept it, that will make the question helpful to others in the future.